# MySQL, single table multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table employees which has this structure:

```
ID | firstName | lastName | reportsTo | jobTitle |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I want to do a single query, which will show me firstName, lastName of employee and which employee He/She does report to (in this column, it contain ID of the employee).

So example of table data:

```
ID | firstName | lastName | reportsTo | jobTitle   |
----------------------------------------------------
35 | John      | Green    | 36        | TeamLeader |
----------------------------------------------------
36 | Annie     | Red      | null        | Supervisor |
----------------------------------------------------
```

So John Green has ID 35 and he reports to Annie Red. How to do this in a query?

So far I have come with basic:

```
SELECT ID, firstName, lastName from employees;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e.ID, e.firstName, e.lastName,ee.firstName, ee.lastName from employees e
JOIN employees ee
ON e.reportsTo=ee.ID
```

The name of the employee and the name which he reports to.

Answer (score 2):

Try with a subquery

```
SELECT ID, firstName, lastName,
( 
    SELECT a.firstName
    FROM employees a
    WHERE a.ID = reportsTo
) as report
from employees;
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer unfortunately. The one below is right, this puts null everywhere in report column.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT A.firstName, A.lastName, B.firstName 'reports to first name', 
B.lastName 'reports to last name'
from employees A JOIN employees B
ON B.ID = A.reportsTo
```

You can check it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22e33f/3